# Loop For - Mix value's array with JS

Tags: javascript

I wish create a loop for display the values of my array, but I don't know how to concate my value and JS. Thank you for you help.

```
function firstCheck() {
    if (firstTime === true) {

        // Default values
        var values = [
            'power01',
            'power04',
            'power07',
            'power10',
            'power17',
            'power19',
            'ac01',
            'fire01',
            'ext01',
            'ext05',
            'site01',
            'site04',
            'site06'
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            //'$scope.currentReporting.'+values[i]+' = $scope.currentReporting.'+values[i]+' === null ? "N" : $scope.currentReporting.'+values[i];    
            $scope.currentReporting.[values[i]] = $scope.currentReporting.[values[i]] === null ? "N" : $scope.currentReporting.[values[i]];    
        }

        firstTime = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in:

```
$scope.currentReporting.[values[i]]
```

Leave out the last period:

```
$scope.currentReporting[values[i]]
```

Comment: @GopinathShiva: That [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13364643) was factually incorrect.